# How to reroute onClose semantic ui modal

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, semantic-ui-react

I'm having trouble trying to reroute onClose of a modal from Semantic UI React.

For some reason, Redirect to tag from react router dom does not trigger the redirect.

Here is the code:

```html
        <Modal size='tiny' closeIcon defaultOpen onClose={() => <Redirect to='/'/>}>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClose={() => this.props.history.push('/')}
```

Try using `history` prop